# Discounting Field From Calculation if Picklist Value Not Selected

Tags: formula, picklist

At the moment if a value is not selected for any of the fields then both Total Points and Total Points Percentage are not calculated.

Is there any way I can check if no value has been selected for Field1-4 and to then discount it from the calculation, so that Total Points is still set.

I am aware that I would most likely need third formula to calculate the value of what total points is divided against.

- Field1 - Picklist value Yes or NO
- Field2 - Picklist value from 1 - 10
- Field3 - Picklist value from 1 - 10
- Field4 - Picklist value from 1 - 10
- Total Points - Formula Number
- Total Points Percentage - Formula Number

Total Points

```
IF(ISPICKVAL(Field1__c,'Yes'),VALUE(TEXT(Field2__c)) +
VALUE(TEXT(Field3__c)) + VALUE(TEXT(4__c)) +
IF(ISPICKVAL(Field1__c,'No'),VALUE(TEXT(0)), 0)
```

Total Points Percentage

```
Total_Point__c / 40 * 100
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change the total points formula to something like this..

```
IF(
   ISPICKVAL(Field1__c,'Yes'),
   (
     BLANKVALUE(Field2__c,0) +
     BLANKVALUE(Field3__c,0) + 
     BLANKVALUE(Field4__c,0)
   ), 
0)
```

the logic goes like.. if Field 1 is Yes, then add the values in Field 2, 3 & 4 if they have a value else use 0 if there is no value on the fields.. and if Field 1 is No, the Total Value will be 0.

Comment: I get the following error, "Error: Field Field1__c is a picklist field. Picklist fields are only supported in certain functions"